# From well formatted string to an array

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, what is the best way to convert a well formatted string (`"4,5,7,2"`) to an array (`[4,5,7,2]`):

`var _intStr="3,5,7,8"` → `var _intArr=[3,5,7,8]`

Comment: Your question is "how do I tokenize a string?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, thanks all for your helps.

I summarized your help in this way:

`String.prototype.toArrInt = function(){`

```
   _intStr =       this.replace(/^,+|,+(,)|,+$/g, '$1').split(',')
   for(var i=0,_intArr=[];i<_intStr.length;_intArr.push(parseInt(_intStr[i++])));
   return _intArr;
```

}

"3,5,6,,5".toArrInt();

Please correct me or improve my final code if is needed.
Thanks,

Antonio

Comment: I would do it like this:
`String.prototype.toIntArray = function() {
    var arr = this.replace(/^,+|,+(,)|,+$/g, '$1').split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i], 10);
    }
    return arr;
};`

Answer (score 5):

```
var _intArr = _intStr.split(",");
```

One thing worth mentioning is that such value `_intStr = "5,,1"` will produce array with **three** items, two are the expected "5" and "1" and one item which is empty string.

Comment: `_instr.replace(/^,+|,+(,)|,+$/g, '$1').split(',')` will remove any empty entries

Answer (score 1):

Use the split function to split by a string or regex.

```
var arr = "1,2".split(",");
```

Now, if you actually want the elements of the resulting array to be numbers instead of strings, you can do something like this:

```
var arr = [];
"1,2,3,4,5".replace(/(?:'[^]*')|(?:[^, ]+)/g, function(match) {
    if (match) {
        arr[arr.length] = parseInt(match, 10);
    }
});
```

Comment: Not sure if the regex is perfect or not though.